# Linq to Sql- Can I build an generic Action of Update?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, business-logic-layer

For each of my tables there is the Key value so my question is how can I get the Key property?
I want to search that object I got in the paramater and update the table through this updated object. how do I find my object from the table?

```
public static void Update<TEntity>(TEntity UpdatedObject) where TEntity : class
        {
            DatabaseLinqDataContext ClientLinq = new DatabaseLinqDataContext(Patch);
            ClientLinq.GetTable<TEntity>()// I want to search that object i got in the paramater and update it. how do I find my object from the table?
            ClientLinq.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Any idea? what is the right way to solve this problem?

**This action in written in the Business Logic Layer.**

Comment: why would you rebuild default linq-to-sql behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few cases to consider.

If the entity instance was previously loaded by this datacontext, just call SubmitChanges.  There's no need to do anything else (all modified instances will be updated at that point).

If the entity instance was previously loaded by a different datacontext, you need to make a new copy which will not be tracked, then follow the next case.

If the entity instance was not loaded by a datacontext (or the instance is a copy from above), then you need to call

```
  //attach the changes to the tracked object graph
dataContext.GetTable<T>().Attach(t, true);
  //if type uses optimistic concurrency, then you need to refresh
  //load the "original" state for the tracked object graph
dataContext.Refresh(t, RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Or, it would be better to call:

```
dataContext.GetTable<T>().Attach(tChanged, tOriginal);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you but what the Attach do? Update the Object in the DB ?